# How can I delete an item in a hashtable and have the keys adjust accordingly?

Tags: android, hashtable

Currently I have a homescreen where the user stores titles of their classes they're taking this semester, and tied to each class is their assignments and flashCards for those classes. When the user long-clicks on one of the items on the homepage, I want to delete the class and all its contents (this includes all flashCards and assignments).

I've stupidly stored my data in hashtables with the keys as integers unfortunately. This has caused some problems when I delete items from the table. The keys are directly correlated to the position on the homescreen, and I can't seem to figure out how to readjust the hashtable when the user deletes something from it.

I've thought about using other data structures such as a arrayList but the problem is that the user could possibly and very likely have only one set of flash cards or only one assignment and it happens to be in the 4th position on the homescreen. This means that I would have to fill the first 3 positions with null first before I could insert the value at the 4th position. I definitely don't think I want that...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that with your current implementation, you will not be able to readjust the numbers in the `HashTable`. I would suggest you use `LinkedList` for the items on your screen and store iterators to the elements in that list in the `HashTable`. This way you will be able to efficiently delete any item.

Comment: completely forgot about linked lists. I'll do some experimenting and come back, ty!

Comment: for some reason, when I delete the position clicked on in the linked List it rearranges the list to close the gaps in between.. so for example Say I have data in positions 1, 2, and 5. I delete the 2nd position, but now my 5 becomes my new 2... instead I want it to become my 4. >.<
Scratch that, I know why it's doing that... just such a pain to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign unique IDs to all entities such as classes, users and assignments.  Use these unique IDs, which may be integers, as keys and in all other places where you need to refer to entities.  Do not use sequential order of entity as identifier, because it may change when item is deleted or even when items are reordered.

Comment: that's what I'm currently doing and the problem is that say you have a list of 10 objects with the keys being 1-10. When you delete the 6th key it leaves a hole and I have to make the 7th key go into the 6th, then the 8th into the 7th and so-forth.

Comment: ID should not be related to position of the object.  So you can have 5 objects with IDs: 1000, 1100, 1300, 1500 and 2000.  Then you delete object with ID 1300.  Now you have 4 objects with ID: 1000, 1100, 1500 and 2000.  No need to change IDs of existing objects after remove.